# jquery Jscroll Not Showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

Can't seem to get Jscroll to show up. I set a color in the style sheet just to test it but I can't get anything to show up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://cheapramen.com/JQuery/jscroll/jscroll.html

Answer (score 0):

there is an error on the page

> $this.innerWidth is not a function

try using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox to help you figure out what is going wrong

**Firebug** is a life-saver when it comes to working with javascript. I highly recommend that you use it.

Comment: where are you seeing that function?

Answer (score 0):

I just spent some time today playing around with jScroll. I noticed your page is using jquery 1.2.3 -- have you tried upgrading it to the latest 1.3.2? I believe there are several new properties/methods in the latest version that were not available in the version you're using (innerWidth being one of them).

Good luck!